Which DICOM Tag should we use to differentiate between the series?
We've been working on DICOM datasets for a while and we have the following problem right now. We have been dealing with the Prostate-MRI case and we have the difficulty to distinguish between different DWI series of one study.
The following DICOM Tags are missing:

Sequence Name (0018,0024),
Sequence Type (0018,0020),
Image Type (0008,0008),
Diffusion Gradient Direction (0018,9075)

Do anyone have any idea through which DICOM Tag we can differentiate between the series besides the ones mentioned above? I'm also attaching the DICOM Tags below to be more understandable.
Structure of the Dataset
We've searched some other DICOM tags and tried to find a way the distinguish between the series.

Series Instance UID (0020,000e) is a safe criterion to determine images belonging to the same series

The series instance UID tag that is mentioned above (0020,000D) is generally the tag that can be used (is generally used) to differentiate images in a single study (ie have the same study UID tag) into separate series.
However, in particular for MR, this may sometimes not be sufficient.
In many MR studies, the images in a single series (ie have the same series UID) will contain images with different scan parameters.
Notably for MR, this often includes images with a different echo time (0018,0081) - in clinical terminology a single series will contain both T1 and T2 images.
From a clinical use (machine or user) perspective, in this case it is further necessary to split the images with the same series UID into subsets that have the same echo time.  Or other acquisition parameters that may be relevant.
Most PACS systems do this type of "series splitting" whenever they display an MR study, and have a list of tags that are used to split series (as defined by having the same series UID) into effectively different series from a clinical point of view.
